# Passing data to a component in render using vue-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '.layers-container',
    render: h => h(App),
})

//This doesn't work, layers undefined
console.log(vm.layers);

//This doesn't work either
vm.layers.push({'name': 'image2'})
```

app.vue using vue-loader:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="item in layers>
        <a :href="item.name"></a>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      layers: [{'name': 'image1'}]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have objects from a canvas that are treated as layers I want to add to this list, so I'm trying to take the instance of Vue and push objects onto it so it then updates the data in the template. But, it seems that I can't actually do that outside of the component itself, and I don't know if I'm just doing it wrong, or if I really have to put the rest of my code into the components.

How would I push the data as exampled above, to the layers array in app.vue?

Comment: Going through the same, the `.vue` component won't actually be the return value of `Vue.new` - instead it will be a child of it; `vm.$children[0]`. But I'm not sure if this is right to do - because it appear that the templates linked to the data doesn't update when I do this.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, did you ever find the answer?

Comment: I didn't figure it out for .vue files. IIRC, I made the vue files into just js files, loading the template from .html files with raw-loader, and having the vue object returned so that its methods can be used. [probably an example](https://gist.github.com/Cyken-Zeraux/db315a9c894889888adf91f063ab3727) You'd use `import * as vuething from "./vuething.js` to load it in your other .js files, or just require() probably. In the project this post was for, this all been replaced by other tech, so I'm unsure if this works now or if I did something different.